# yii model save() not running

Tags: php, yii

I am currently trying to upload images and save the file name in a database.  The Table is called Images and it only has 3 variables, ID image, and listing_ID.  When i try to save, I am not getting an error, the images are renamed and uploaded, but i am not getting an entry on the table.  I think it might be because my php file that saves the images is in my root directory(outside of the protected folder) but i may be wrong.  Can anyone shed some light on this or how to fix this?

local url is : mylocalmachine/index.php/listings/upload_images/1
listing_ID : 1;

php code : http://pastie.org/9770341

The file just renames the image for saving, and should enter in a row into the Images table.

```
<?php
$output_dir = "uploads/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
$ret = array();

$error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
{

    if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
    {
        $RandomNum   = time();

        $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
        $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

        $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
        $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
        $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
        $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $NewImageName);
        //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

        $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;

        $image_entry = new Images;
        $image_entry->image = $NewImageName;
        $image_entry->listing_ID = $listing_ID;
        $image_entry->save();

    }
    else
    {
        $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
        for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
        {
            $RandomNum   = time();

            $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]));
            $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type'][$i]; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

            $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
            $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
            $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
            $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

            $ret[$NewImageName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$NewImageName );

            $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $exploded_url = explode('/',$url);
            $listing_ID = end($exploded_url);

            $image_entry = new Images;
            $image_entry->image = $NewImageName;
            $image_entry->listing_ID = $listing_ID;
            $image_entry->save();
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($ret);

}

?>
```

Comment: Don't just link to code, include it here so that others who come later can still be helped if your link goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$fileName isn't set.  it should be  $ret['fileName']= $output_dir.$NewImageName;

Answer (score 1):

If you call `save()` it will run validation and return false if that fails.
You have to check the return value an act accordingly. The following code will print all validation errors in case validation fails:

```
if (!$image_entry->save()) {
    print_r($image_entry->getErrors();)
}
```

Comment: I am unable to print_r on a post file bc i am doing this in ajax.

Comment: check the console output in firebug or similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

probably your model does not pass validation

use

```
$image_entry->validate();
```

to check validation result
(return boolean whether the validation is successful without any error.)

use

```
$image_entry->getErrors()
```

to get validation errors array

or use

```
$image_entry->save(false);
```

to save without validation

Comment: It was passing all validation.  It was a variable issue